# SQL-Server: Truncate of transaction-logs inf FULL-BACKUP-Mode

Tags: sql-server

I found a link expaining very well the main factors of transaction-log. But there is 1 statements I don't understand completly:

> The FULL recovery model means that every part of every operation is
>   logged, which is called being fully logged. Once a full database
>   backup has been taken in the FULL recovery model, the transaction log
>   will not automatically truncate until a log backup is taken. If you do
>   not want to make use of log backups and the ability to recover a
>   database to a specific point in time, do not use the FULL recovery
>   model. However, if you wish to use database mirroring, then you have
>   no choice, as it only supports the FULL recovery model.

My question are:
Will the transaction-logs get truncated if I have a database in Full-Backup-Mode but have neither taken an full-backup than an log-backup? Will the free space overwriten after next checkpoint? And when will those checkpoints be reached? Do I need to set a soze limit for the transaction logs to force the truncation or not?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The transaction log will not be reused before the log or the database get backed up in Full recovery model. And it will be truncated only when you truncate the log.

Comment: Your transaction log will keep on growing until the disk is full. You do NOT want that to happen. Either switch to Simple Recovery model, or add a transaction log backup job.

Answer (score 1):

When your database is in full recovery mode,only log backup frees the space in log file..

This space won't be available for file system,but will be internally marked as free,so that new transactions can use this space

> Will the free space overwriten after next checkpoint? And when will those checkpoints be reached? Do I need to set a size limit for the transaction logs to force the truncation or not?

You need not do anything,just ensure log backups are taken depending on your requirements